# Принудительный вызов запроса на разрешения использования камеры и микрофона

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Каким способом правильнее вызывать данный запрос в браузере принудительно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как можно проверить разрешен ли доступ к ним (микрофон, камера, звук) уже? Заранее благодарю за советы

Comment: Что значит принудительно? Вы хотите показывать это уведомление до тех пор пока пользователь не согласится?

Comment: По нажатию кнопки, так как уведомление о запросе иногда не приходят

Comment: Может подразумевается принудительно разрешать?

Comment: Нужно по нажатию кнопки вызвать выжеуказанный запрос\уведомление (фото) для разрешения микрофон\камера